# Redirect AMP page depending on geo location

Tags: amp-html

I know that amp-geo can be used to detect the user‘s approximate location in order to do css-based geo-aware styling.

However, in my case I’d like to automatically redirect the user to another URL depending on their geo location.

For example, if a user from the US opens my example.com, I’d like to redirect them to example.com/US.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I solved it via CloudFront redirection.